# Align multiple stacked items vertically at different positions using CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have tried using CSS Grid and CSS Flex to achieve it, but can't achieve it completely.

**Requirement:**

I have a container inside which I have multiple items,
each item has a configuration of top, centre and bottom as vertical alignments.
All the top items should appear at the top, all centre items at the centre and all bottom items at the bottom of the parent.

The items are dynamic means there can be any number of the item and each item can have any position(Top, Centre, Bottom).

The only restriction given to the user is that they will add the items in order means 1st he will add top items, then centre items and then bottom items.

[image]

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child top"> Item 1</div>
    <div class="child top"> Item 2</div>
    <div class="child center"> Item 3</div>
    <div class="child center">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 5</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add code that you tried

Comment: I tried using flex align-self, justify-content

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to add new box dynamically? If so, you need javascript for that. You can't just add in css. CSS is just styling. If you are seeking a function, then you need javascript.

Comment: Ya new items can be added, but it's available during the page load time, not added after page load, so want to avoid js

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `order` and pseudo elements. The trick is that both pseudo elements will be between the top/center and bottom/center and will fill all the space. You can also have the element scrambled, the HTML order doesn't matter:

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  border:2px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.parent > * {
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.top { order:1}
.parent:before {
  content:"";
  order:2;
  flex:1
}
.center { order:3}
.parent:after {
  content:"";
  order:4;
  flex:1
}
.bottom { order:5}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child center"> Item 3</div>
    <div class="child top"> Item 1</div>
    <div class="child center">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 5</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 6</div>
    <div class="child top"> Item 2</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 7</div>
    <div class="child top"> Item 8</div>
</div>
```

Another idea since you said that the order will be respected is to consider the `+` selector and auto margin:

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  border:2px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.parent > * {
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.top + .center {
  margin-top:auto;
}

.center + .bottom {
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child top"> Item 1</div>
    <div class="child top"> Item 2</div>
    <div class="child center"> Item 3</div>
    <div class="child center">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 5</div>
    <div class="child bottom"> Item 6</div>
</div>
```